# How to reduce particle cpu usage in unity3d?

Tags: unity-game-engine, profiler, particle-system

Hello I design game in unity3d but particle take huge cpu usage hoa can I  reduce cpu usage of particle system in unity3d?

my unity version is 2017.1.f03

Comment: How many particles are you emitting?

Comment: https://unity3d.com/how-to/particle-systems-performance-tips#five-performance-tips

Comment: max particles = 10000

Comment: rate over time=0

Comment: rate over distance = 10

Comment: That doesnt answer the question, how many particles are you emitting?  Max particles is 10000 that is ALOT of particles for one emitter. but are you emitting 10,000 particles?  what is the life of your particle?